# calling a method on LoadingCache refresh

Tags: java, guava

I have a client who provides access to their apis  through tokens. They are not OAuth tokens. Just a simple http get request to get the token. This token does expire and we can refresh before that to get a new token. I was thinking of implementing this using Google LoadingCache, get the  token if not null, else  post as request to the client to get the token. But this happens when the value is null. ( in my case first time ) Afterwards, I just need to refresh periodically before it expires.Does using Loading cache make sense here ? or are there any other ways of achieving this?
Also if it does this is the approach I am thinking --- I would like it to call  a function/method to refresh the token. I am not sure if overloading the load method will be called only if its null or everytime it has to refresh/expire. Will the cache emptied  when it expires/refreshes? I can refresh the token using the previous token. So I need the value in the cache to send the request. Here is what I am thinking

```
     private static LoadingCache<String, Optional<String>> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .build(new CacheLoader<String, Optional<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Optional<String> load(String key) throws Exception {
                return Optional.fromNullable(refreshToken(key));
            }
        });
```

I think I need to know if the same load method will be called when the cache expires?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you call `LoadingCache.get()` it will invoke your `load()` method. However cached values do not automatically expire - you must either manually remove them (e.g. via `Cache.invalidate()`) or [configure the desired eviction semantics](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#eviction) via `CacheBuilder`.

For example if you know tokens expire after 10 minute you could use `expireAfterWrite(9, TimeUnit.MINUTES)` (9 minutes gives you some buffer time, you could pick a different amount of time).

On the other hand if you only find out that a token has expired by making a request and having it be rejected you'd likely want to manually invalidate the entry after the request fails. Then the next call to `.get()` will invoke `.load()` and then return a new token.